# iOS device - data update

Tags: ios, csv, nsurlconnection

What is the most relevant and best way to update data on an iOS device from a - CSV file on a remote server that receives values every second?
The file receives data every second and this data is to be updated. Currently im using an NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection to read the file for every 10seconds. Instead is there any other way I can update the device on the new data? like webservices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either your current approach and web services are pulling data from the source on repeatable manner, which is fine if it's not a time-critical solution.

however, if you need a "push" feature, which means clients get called immediately after new data is available, you may consider using socket programming. You may want to check out the wonderful framework [CocoaAsyncSocket on github](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket)

Comment: Push feature is good but the data keeps coming in for every second. Since its a CSV file would using JSON features help? or any database? Because currently im reading the whole file for every 10 seconds. However I need the data of the newly added values. is there file scanner options ?

Comment: who's inserting the new data into the CSV file? a server-side program?

Comment: yup a java program runs adds the new data every second on the client side. Server receives the file

Comment: why not let the java dev write some APIs for you?